# RMP's download progress is seemingly stuck

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I've tried to use the new Progress Notification of RMP. The upload direction seems to work fine.
The download direction however seemingly doesn't work correctly. I've set it up like this:

`self.token = session!.addProgressNotification(for: .download, mode: .reportIndefinitely)`

Upon launching my app I'm receiving two notifications with progress object:

`Progress(transferredBytes: 105, transferrableBytes: 9894)`

and that's it. Nothing happens. 
Any idea?

Comment: It seems I am experiencing the same problem with Upload too. Just a single report `Progress(transferredBytes: 17002, transferrableBytes: 18095)` and then nothing. The token stored strongly in the class.

Comment: It seems that after deleting the app from the simulator it started working again. So it suggests the app may have stopped syncing before.